# How to make VSCode Intellisense ignore certain folders but still have them appear in the Explorer window

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a large C project which contains generated files among the source code. These will have names like g_*.c or be in directories named "out". I would like to have these generated files excluded from Intellisense, to speed up jump-to-definition. I have tried adding them to files.exclude:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/g_*": true,
    "**/out": true
}
```

However, this not only excludes them from Intellisense, but also removes them from the explorer window, so I cannot browse the files. Is there a way to exclude the files from Intellisense, but still make them appear in the Explorer window so that they are browsable?

Comment: what do  you mean excluded by intellinse? just quick suggestions list that comes by ctrl+space?

Comment: Intellisense builds a library of tags that you can use to do things like Jump To Definition (F12). I want Intellisense to ignore the code in the generated files, since there is a lot of them and they are slowing down the Jump To Definition action.

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I am in similar situation to you..

Comment: Unfortunately not. Hopefully someone has some way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the settings key: files.watcherExclude

This maybe keep vscode aware of the files, but make vscode less slower even with them.

Its...
Configure paths or glob patterns to exclude from file watching. Paths can either be relative to the watched folder or absolute. Glob patterns are matched relative from the watched folder. When you experience the file watcher process consuming a lot of CPU, make sure to exclude large folders that are of less interest (such as build output folders).